# tinyMCE & wordpress giving odd characters... tried combination of solutions

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to embed a flash video into a custom setup of the tinyMCE editor. It is seperate from the main WordPress one, but it is still within the wordpress admin area.

The output code from a simple youtube embed block is as follows:

```
<p><img mce_src=\"../wp-content/themes/porcelain/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/media/img/trans.gif\" src=\"../wp-content/themes/porcelain/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/media/img/trans.gif\" width=\"560\" height=\"340\" style=\"\" class=\"mceItemFlash\" title=\"&quot;allowFullScreen&quot;:&quot;true&quot;,&quot;allowscriptaccess&quot;:&quot;always&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;http://www.youtube.com/v/26Ywp6vUQMY&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;&quot;,&quot;allowfullscreen&quot;:&quot;true&quot;\"></p>
```

As you can see, it's escaping the quotes when I don't want it to...

Any help is massively appreciated, and I know this is a school boy error. I just need setting straight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This often happens when you have code that escapes data before using it in SQL (as it should do) on a server that has php's [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/magic_quotes) feature enabled. This feature causes php to automatically escape get and post data when it loads. If you then escape it again, things go wrong - it gets double escaped, so escaped data goes into the db.

PHP has now deprecated this feature, they realised it was a nuiscance, caused more pain than it saved - they were trying to build in security, but ultimately the developer needs to be aware of and work around security issues, rather than having them taken care of silently. Myself, I ended up regularly including code in stuff to detect if this was enabled and reverse it early in the execution if it was.

Comment: I think you're probably right here. I am saving the data to a mySQL database. That's a real pain if this is the case... hmm. 

What I'm trying to do is create a nice little plugin for wordpress, so I want to avoid touching the core files, and I also want others to be able to use this plugin without much technical knowledge (in face, virtually no technical knowledge)... so creating php.ini files etc is a big ask. 

I may have to reconsider how I will get a video embedded in the document.

Comment: just ended up doing str_replace on the both end of the echo... sometimes the answer is so simple!!!

Comment: there should be a way to fix this "properly" rather than working round, as i doubt wordpress is actually broken in this regard, as it'd break blog posts etc. at the moment the data is wrong in your database, be best to fix it in a way that made that correct,

Comment: agreed, but time was of the essence. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are transfering your data through $_POST it is escaped if [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is enabled (it's deprecated now and automatically removed from PHP 5.4 and above). Just use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stripslashes.php) if it's escaped, fixed my problems with HTML being escaped in wordpress using tinymce, at least.

Comment: Kind of funny I ran into this problem again, and I searched stackoverflow for an answer — and came to my own solution. Good thing I learn from my mistakes..

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen using "the_editor()" and "wp_editor()" functions. I don't think my server has magic quotes enabled, because I didn't enable it, and I installed everything.

Either way, I added stripslashes... everywhere.

When I call the editor:

```
<?php wp_editor(stripslashes($custom_text), 'custom_text'); ?>
```

When I go to save the POST data:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['custom_text']) ) {
    update_option('my_custom_text', esc_sql(stripslashes($_POST['custom_text'])));
    $updated = true;
}
```

And when I retrieve the stored data:

```
$custom_text = apply_filters( 'the_content', stripslashes(get_option('my_custom_text')) );
```

This fixed it for me, though I would love to know if there is another way. I thought the filters had this built in, I was wrong, but I wonder if there isn't something else I am missing.